# RecyclerView + CardView: Inflating Wrong Data

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, layout-inflater

Im using CardView to create a list of cards with newsletters. The basic elements are 3 TextViews + 1 ImageView. I cant inflate 2 elements properly: the title is fine, but the link text the gets the wrong string(it gets the string referring to the body text) and the body TextView dont change at all.

Aeres a picture with the general ideia:

[preview on android studio (left) and app running on device(right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh12Y.jpg)

This is my CardView XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".News">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card1_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/news_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="articleTitle articleTitle articleTitle articleTitle articleTitle articleTitle articleTitle articleTitle articleTitle articleTitle articleTitle articleTitle articleTitle articleTitle "
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/news_link"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:text="http://www.articleLink.com/" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/news_body"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:text="Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body ..."
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/news_photoId"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="145dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:src="@drawable/enfnotum" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingEnd="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:text="Coments    Share" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#bab7b7" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

RecycleView list layout XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".News">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Now the java classes:
Here im populating the list, calling the adapter

```
 public class News extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView rv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

        initializeData();
        initializeAdapter();
    }

    private void initializeData() {
        articles.add(new Article("0title", "0link", "0body", R.drawable.enfnotum));
        articles.add(new Article("1title", "1link", "1body", R.drawable.enfnoticias));
        articles.add(new Article("2title", "2link", "2body", R.drawable.image1));
        articles.add(new Article("3title", "3link", "3body", R.drawable.image2));
        articles.add(new Article("4title", "4link", "4body", R.drawable.image3));
        articles.add(new Article("5title", "5link", "5body", R.drawable.enfnotum));
        articles.add(new Article("6title", "6link", "6body", R.drawable.image3));
        articles.add(new Article("7title", "7link", "7body", R.drawable.enfnoticias));
        //TODO: database
    }

    private void initializeAdapter() {
        NewsRVAdapter adapter = new NewsRVAdapter(articles);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

My classe to create the list object, few getters

```
    public class Article {

    private String articleTitle;
    private String articleLink;
    private String articleBody;
    private int articlePhotoId;

    public Article(String articleTitle, String articleLink, String articleBody, int articlePhotoId) {
        this.articleTitle = articleTitle;
        this.articleLink = articleLink;
        this.articleBody = articleBody;
        this.articlePhotoId = articlePhotoId;
    }

    public String getArticleTitle() {
        return articleTitle;
    }

    public String getArticleLink() {
        return articleLink;
    }

    public String getArticleBody() {
        return articleBody;
    }

    public int getArticlePhotoId() {
        return articlePhotoId;
    }
}
```

Inflating the layout

```
    public class NewsRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsRVAdapter.ArticleViewHolder> {

    List<Article> articles;

    NewsRVAdapter(List<Article> articles) {
        this.articles = articles;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public ArticleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_item_list, viewGroup, false);
        return new ArticleViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ArticleViewHolder ArticleViewHolder, int position) {
        ArticleViewHolder.articleTitle.setText(articles.get(position).getArticleTitle());
        ArticleViewHolder.articleLink.setText(articles.get(position).getArticleLink());
        ArticleViewHolder.articleLink.setText(articles.get(position).getArticleBody());
        ArticleViewHolder.articlePhotoID.setImageResource(articles.get(position).getArticlePhotoId());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return articles.size();
    }

    public static class ArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cv;
        TextView articleTitle;
        TextView articleLink;
        TextView articleBody;
        ImageView articlePhotoID;

        ArticleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card1_view);
            articleTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
            articleLink = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_link);
            articleBody = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_body);
            articlePhotoID = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_photoId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo error. Try to replace your `NewsRVAdapter`'s `onBindViewHolder` with:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ArticleViewHolder ArticleViewHolder, int position) {
ArticleViewHolder.articleTitle.setText(articles.get(position).getArticleTitle());
ArticleViewHolder.articleLink.setText(articles.get(position).getArticleLink());
ArticleViewHolder.articleBody.setText(articles.get(position).getArticleBody());
ArticleViewHolder.articlePhotoID.setImageResource(articles.get(position).getArticlePhotoId());
}
```

Comment: I cant belive... ty so much

Answer (score 1):

The reason is your wrong code in **onBindViewHolder** ^^

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ArticleViewHolder ArticleViewHolder, int position) {
    ArticleViewHolder.articleTitle.setText(articles.get(position).getArticleTitle());
    ArticleViewHolder.**articleLink**.setText(articles.get(position).getArticleLink());
    ArticleViewHolder.**articleLink**.setText(articles.get(position).getArticleBody());
    ArticleViewHolder.articlePhotoID.setImageResource(articles.get(position).getArticlePhotoId());
}
```

ArticleViewHolder.**articleLink** was assigned two times so its value was overriden.

Correct it and your code work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake on `onBindViewHolder`. You were referencing to `articleLink` twice.

it should have been

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ArticleViewHolder ArticleViewHolder, int position){
    ArticleViewHolder.articleTitle.setText(articles.get(position).getArticleTitle());
    ArticleViewHolder.articleLink.setText(articles.get(position).getArticleLink());
    ArticleViewHolder.articleBody.setText(articles.get(position).getArticleBody());
    ArticleViewHolder.articlePhotoID.setImageResource(articles.get(position).getArticlePhotoId());
}
```